# ionic ng-if only show selected content

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I want some code to show or hide some content (a text).

```
HTML
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let act of questions.test; let i = index">
        {{act.quote}}
      <ion-item>
          <div ng-if="i == 2">
            THIS IS 2 {{i}}
         </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


TS
    this.questions =
      {
    "test":[
    {
      "quote": "first row"
    }, {
      "quote": "second row"
    }, {
      "quote": "third row"
    }, {
      "quote": "fourth row"
    }
    ],
```

I just want to show the "THIS IS 2" when it's the second element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing angular 1 and 2 together. Ionic 2 uses angular 2, so if you are in fact using ionic 2 (your `*ngFor` directive indicates you are) then you must use the `if` for angular 2 which is `*ngIf`, [check out the documentation for the directive here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

```
<div *ngIf="i == 2">
    THIS IS 2 {{i}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "ng-if".
Apparently it's from another version of Angular.
Use "ngIf" instead.